# How to express dissatisfaction on a poor rating during an appraisal

Tags: professionalism, performance-reviews

In most organisations an employee is given a certain **performance rating** as per their year end appraisal.

In most cases, the employees are given an option to provide their **comment** on this rating.

I want to know how to **express my dissatisfaction professionally** on a poor rating as my comment during the appraisal process.

Comment: So what´s the cause of your dissatisfaction? Professionally => stay objective! In it´s current state it is a little bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Professionally => I do not want to shout back and say I AM NOT HAPPY WITH THE RATING. Instead, politely want to express my dissatisfaction.

Comment: But what makes you unhappy - that it happens to be bad, or is there wrong facts in it?

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the Rating? Was it unfair? Do you fell like it didn't cover the full scope of your work? do you Need more clarification as to why the Rating was as it was?

Comment: Do you only have a rating? Or have you got a proper appraisal document which outlines why you received that rating?

Comment: Write down a list of achievements you made and bring it with you to the review. On lower ratings, bring up the point that you made all these achievements and you feel the score should be higher to reflect that.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to achieve by expressing disapproval? Do you expect them to revise the rating, or do you just want to make it known you disagree with it, or something else?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord: You got it right.. If its not satisfactory, I would definitely ask for clarification.

Comment: @MaskedMan: Yeah! I just want to make it known to them that I disagree with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in any case, thank them for their feedback. *(Really, there are places where you do not get that! You are just fired out of the blue and never knew anyone was not happy with your performance)*

Then, depending on whats wrong:

1. If there are objectively wrong facts: Present proof and request the rating to be changed. This is your chance to set things straight. Avoid any accusation or hard feelings, take it as a misunderstanding.
2. If they have a subjectively different view on things: Tell them that you are surprised they have that perception of you. Maybe inquire why that is the case so you can change this for the better.
3. You flat out failed: Think about how you can improve. Talk about it an set goals to achieve better ratings on your next rating.

In any case it is hard to stay cool and objective in these situations sometime. If you feel you want to shout or feel emotional, just thank them and tell them you have to think about it. Then you can come back to them when you slept it over.

Never tell them they are wrong unless you can objectively prove it. This just makes you look guilty. It is their perception of you and you´ll have to live with it, to a certain degree. But now that you have knowledge about it you can do something in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your lovely answer. #2 somehow goes with me..!

Answer (score 1):

The employer surely gave some reasons for the rating. If you disagree with those reasons, you need to present arguments to the contrary.

If they did not provide reasons, insist that they do so you can improve.

Do not merely complain without presenting a case.